# How to set property of selected ng-options item with ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to set a property of the selected item in an ng-options set in a html select by pointing ng-model to it, essentially, I want to define an array like

data = [{option : "meow", answer : ""}, {option : "woof", answer : ""}]

And have two select's showing the options 'meow' and 'woof'. If the 1st select is set to 'woof', the data should then look like

[{option : "meow", answer : "woof"}, {option : "woof", answer : ""}]

The idea being you'd display

A cat goes [meow/woof] a dog goes [meow/woof].

I've tried

```html
<select type="name" ng-model="item.answer" ng-options="item.answer as item.option for item in data" required></select>
```

but no dice... there seems to be a scoping problem with item (or perhaps a value/reference) problem, but I'm not sure :/

I've created a Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/qPpW3x0SAHxTiX7SzPEM to demonstrate.

Full repro

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('gap', function () {
  return {
      transclude: true,      
      template: '<select type="name" ng-model="item.answer" ng-options="item.answer as item.option for item in data" required></select>',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attr) {
            // some code
        }
    }
});

app.directive('ngHtmlCompile', function($compile)
{
    return {
        restrict: 'A',      
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngHtmlCompile, function(newValue, oldValue)
            {
                element.html(newValue);

                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            });
        }
    }
});

app.controller('TestController', function($scope) 
{
  $scope.html = "A cat goes <gap></gap> a dog goes <gap/>";
  $scope.data = [{option : "meow", answer : ""}, {option : "woof", answer : ""}]
});

    //var UsersService = $resource('/auth/users', {});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.11" data-semver="1.3.11" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.11/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TestController">
  <div ng-html-compile="html"></div>
  <br>
  <br>
  Current output<br>
  {{data}}<br>
  Desired output<br>
  [{"option":"meow","answer":"meow"},{"option":"woof","answer":"woof"}]<br>
</div>

</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: Your question is not clear. elaborate it properly..

Comment: You should include the minimal and relevant code that "doesn't work" in the question. Question should be self-sustaining, even when links don't work

Comment: Apologies, have elaborated and added code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... one needs to prototypically inherit the scope (scope : true)

Tag each element with an index (so we know which element we're talking about), then in the inherited scope copy across the option instance, so we can use it with ng-model.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

var gapIndex = 0;

app.directive('gap', function () {
  return {
      transclude: true,   
      scope : true,
      template: '<select type="name" ng-model="item.answer" ng-options="item.option as item.option for item in data" required></select>',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attr) {
            $element.tag = gapIndex++;
            $scope.item = $scope.data[$element.tag];
        }
    }
});


app.directive('ngHtmlCompile', function($compile)
{
    return {
        restrict: 'A',      
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngHtmlCompile, function(newValue, oldValue)
            {
                element.html(newValue);

                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            });
        }
    }
});

app.controller('TestController', function($scope) 
{
  $scope.html = "A cat goes <gap></gap> a dog goes <gap/>";
  $scope.data = [{option : "meow", answer : ""}, {option : "woof", answer : ""}]
});
```